# Cross-site Cookie Access

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, raspberry-pi3

Bear with me here-I'm a new/training full stack developer.

I'm hoping to develop a remote kiosk with a raspberry pi that hosts a small web app.  I've turned the kiosk into an access point and plan on forwarding all network traffic to the raspberry pi webserver's homepage where a user will fill out a form (similar to a captive portal, except there is never any access to the internet beyond the raspberry pi).

In my webpage, I'm planning on saving cookies (using javascript's document.cookie) to the user's device.  From what I understand, browsers will only allow access to this cookie from the site that saved it.

I wanted to assure the security of the cookies that are saved on the user's device (no passwords, but an email address is in there).  If I serve my local page from the local domain name "www.hiker-log.com", if my user eventually leaves the captive portal, connects to the web, and visits www.hiker-log.com, would they be able to access the cookies that I have stored?  Or are cookies secured on an IP-basis, not a domain-basis?  For example, if my intranet page's domain name matches one on the web, could someone from that website grab the cookies that were written from my website on the same domain name?

From a curiosity perspective, couldn't my little captive portal pretty much just spoof the domain and/or ip of any website it wanted and make off with client cookies from any website?  Even without that user visiting the site (with an "external" javascript call)?

Comment: Cookies are stored on a **browser** basis; neither an IP basis nor domain basis. But if your user accesses your site from a different IP (and the same browser on the same machine), then yes, they will retain the cookies. Consider accessing StackOverflow from work / home on the same laptop :)

Comment: Sorry about that!  I have rephrased the question.  I meant to ask whether the browser recognizes the server's IP or domain name when determining what cookies can be read.  For example, if my intranet page's domain name matches one on the web, could someone from that website grab the cookies that were written from my website on the same domain name?

Comment: **That** is based on the domain name; you would have one cookie associated to `www.hiker-log.com`. And you can't simply spoof a domain in order to obtain cookies from there; Intranet and the proper web are considered different domains.